# Assigning Colours to each Instance of a value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a program in which there are two sets of numbers in two set columns, like sender and receiver numbers. I want to assign each instance of a value a colour that is unique to that number. However if a sender number is in the receiver column and vice versa, the two should have the same colour between the two columns.

I have this so far which works within one column. I have tried playing with the column variables:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunctio
If target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    If target.Column = 3 Then
    x = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    x = wf.Match(target.Value, _
        Range("C1").Resize(target.Row - 1), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If x > 0 Then
        target.Interior.Color = Cells(x, 3).Interior.Color
        Else
            target.Interior.Color = RGB( _
                wf.RandBetween(125, 255), wf.RandBetween(125, 255), wf.RandBetween(125, 255))
        End If
    End If
End If

If target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    If target.Column = 5 Then
    x = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    x = wf.Match(target.Value, _
        Range("e1").Resize(target.Row - 1), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If x > 0 Then
        target.Interior.Color = Cells(x, 5).Interior.Color
        Else
            target.Interior.Color = RGB( _
                wf.RandBetween(125, 255), wf.RandBetween(125, 255), wf.RandBetween(125, 255))
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What sort of numbers are they?  If they were all less than 16,777,216 then you could assign the RGB code based on the number itself rather than selecting a random (and potentially non-unique) value.

Comment: They're phone numbers, so that wont work unfortunately. e.g. 6427XXXXXXX

Comment: If only the last 7 digits change, that is less than 16,777,216.  (Or, even if the leading digits did change, if you were happy to have a 1 in 10 million chance of non-unique colours, just take the number mod 10000000 and use that.)

Comment: I am thinking of somehow converting the last digits in the phone number to a hex or RGB code, as this is the last few digits of a phone number, these are likely to be unique, also the variable within the equation will be the same, meaning that each number will get the same colour which is what I want, I will post what I come up with

Comment: Can the same number appear more than once in the same column?

Comment: Yes, the sheet shows a conversation between phone numbers, so assigning each phone number a unique colour will make the data easier to read.

Comment: Just remember that an RGB code is simply a number between 0 and 16777215.  There's no real conversion necessary, except to make two colours visibly distinguishable from each other (e.g. `target.Interior.Color = 12345678` is going to be hard to distinguish from `target.Interior.Color = 12345679` - they both look very bluish).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following `Change` event will set the colour of any **new** value entered into either column C or E, utilising the `FindColour` function to obtain the existing colour for that value anywhere else in column C or E (not necessarily only in rows above it).

The `ResetThem` subroutine clears out all formatting on columns C and E and then resets the colours starting from scratch.  (Useful if you already have data in those columns which hasn't yet been coloured.)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Column = 3 Or Target.Column = 5 Then
            Target.Interior.Color = FindColour(Target.Value)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Function FindColour(v As Variant) As Long
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    On Error Resume Next
    x = 0
    'See if value exists in column C
    x = wf.Match(v, Range("C:C"), 0)
    If x > 0 Then
        If Cells(x, "C").Interior.Color <> vbWhite Then
            FindColour = Cells(x, "C").Interior.Color
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
    'See if value exists in column E
    x = wf.Match(v, Range("E:E"), 0)
    If x > 0 Then
        If Cells(x, "E").Interior.Color <> vbWhite Then
            FindColour = Cells(x, "E").Interior.Color
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
    'Assign a random colour
    FindColour = RGB(wf.RandBetween(125, 255), wf.RandBetween(125, 255), wf.RandBetween(125, 255))
End Function

Sub ResetThem()
    With Columns("C").Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Columns("E").Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Dim r As Long
    'Starting at row 2 to avoid assigning a colour to headings
    ' (change "2" to "1", or some other number, as appropriate)
    For r = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(r, "C").Value) Then
            Cells(r, "C").Interior.Color = FindColour(Cells(r, "C").Value)
        End If
    Next r
    For r = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(r, "E").Value) Then
            Cells(r, "E").Interior.Color = FindColour(Cells(r, "E").Value)
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

---

One potential problem is that, if a value is entered into a cell when that same value already exists in a cell below it in the same column but doesn't exist in the other column, a new colour will be assigned.  There are ways around that issue, but I'm not sure whether it will occur in your situation, so I haven't catered for it.

Comment: This goes in the worksheet module, Is there a way to add this programatically to a newly generated sheet?

Comment: @ohnoohdear There are ways, but using VBA to write VBA is beyond the scope of this question.  (And probably beyond my skills to answer!)  So it would be better to ask that in another question so that it gets the attention it deserves.

Comment: @ohnoohdear, do post the second question. There's an easy solution using Application events.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have things backwards.  You are using the match function on the same column you are editing when you should be using the match function on the other column.  You are also resizing the range on the same column which could have more or less rows than your other column which could limit the range to find an exact match on the opposite column.

I changed you code just a little and I got it to work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
If target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    If target.Column = 5 Then
    x = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    x = wf.Match(target.Value, _
        Range("C1:C" & [C3000].End(xlUp).Row), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If x > 0 Then
        target.Interior.Color = Cells(x, 3).Interior.Color
        Else
            target.Interior.Color = RGB( _
                wf.RandBetween(125, 255), wf.RandBetween(125, 255), wf.RandBetween(125, 255))
        End If
    End If
End If

If target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    If target.Column = 3 Then
    x = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    x = wf.Match(target.Value, _
        Range("E1:E" & [E3000].End(xlUp).Row), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If x > 0 Then
        target.Interior.Color = Cells(x, 5).Interior.Color
        Else
            target.Interior.Color = RGB( _
                wf.RandBetween(125, 255), wf.RandBetween(125, 255), wf.RandBetween(125, 255))
        End If
    End If
End If
```

End Sub

I just switched the target.Column = # and the range reference in each loop to look at the opposite column.  One last thing to note there is a slim possibility of getting the same color on a different number using the randomization.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. 

There is about a 1 in 8,000,000 chance of getting the same colour, and there aren't a lot of unique numbers that appear on the same page. I was thinking that in the event of a duplicate colour being generated, the sheet could just be re-generated from the raw data so this is not a problem.