# Each instance of a value gets the same colour and new values get a new colour

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I recently asked the question, here:
[Assigning Colours to each Instance of a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46063772/assigning-colours-to-each-instance-of-a-value/46064675),
however this ended up not working for me and I was unsure if I should carry on in that thread or start a new one because I have changed some things. Here is my new code, it alternates cell selection between two columns and changes the colour of the selected cell, however if the number already exists, I want them to have the same colour. What I have now, doesnt seem to match and assigns a random colour despite there being matches.

```
Sub colourNumbers()
Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
Dim analysisSheet As Worksheet
Set analysisSheet = ActiveSheet
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For a = 3 To lastRow

    If b = 3 Then
    b = 5
        Else
            b = 3
    End If

    If b = 5 Then
        a = a - 1
    End If

analysisSheet.Cells(a, b).Select
With Selection
x = 0
On Error Resume Next
x = wf.Match(Selection.Value, _
    Range("C3:E" & [C3000].End(xlUp).Row), 0)
On Error GoTo 0
If x > 0 Then
    target.Interior.Color = Cells(x, 3).Interior.Color
    Else
        Selection.Interior.Color = RGB( _
            wf.RandBetween(125, 255), wf.RandBetween(125, 255), wf.RandBetween(125, 255))
    End If
End With
Next a
End Sub
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: match function takes a range of single col as lookup array... so in your case it is throwing error compile time itself but you are not able to see it because of the ignore error statement that you have added.
So you are changing color of col C and E only, so I am guessing you are intending to search the key in both of these col itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming: -  As you are changing color of col C and E only, so I am guessing you are intending to search the presence of the number in C and E only... so Col D is of no significance here...

```
 Option Explicit

Sub colourNumbers()

Dim a, x, x1, x2, b, lastRow, lastCol As Long
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Dim analysisSheet As Worksheet
Dim rng1, rng2 As Range

Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
Set analysisSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")


lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row


Set rng1 = analysisSheet.Range("C3:C" & lastRow)
Set rng2 = analysisSheet.Range("E3:E" & lastRow)

lastCol = 3

For a = 3 To lastRow

    If b = 3 Then
        b = 5
    Else
        b = 3
    End If

    If b = 5 Then
        a = a - 1
    End If




x = 0
x1 = 0
x2 = 0

On Error Resume Next
x1 = wf.Match(analysisSheet.Cells(a, b).Value, rng1, 0) + 2 ' match function offset from where the array starts
On Error GoTo 0

On Error Resume Next
x2 = wf.Match(analysisSheet.Cells(a, b).Value, rng2, 0) + 2
On Error GoTo 0


If x1 = 0 And x2 > 0 Then
    x = x2
ElseIf x2 = 0 And x1 > 0 Then
    x = x1
ElseIf x2 > 0 And x1 > 0 Then
    x = x1 'pick anyone
Else
    x = 0
End If


'Debug.Print x
'Debug.Print analysisSheet.Cells(a, b).Value



If x > 0 And x <> a And b = lastCol Then
    'Debug.Print "Same"
    analysisSheet.Cells(a, b).Interior.Color = analysisSheet.Cells(x, 3).Interior.Color
    lastCol = b

ElseIf x > 0 And x = a And b <> lastCol Then
   ' Debug.Print "Same2"
    analysisSheet.Cells(a, b).Interior.Color = analysisSheet.Cells(x, 3).Interior.Color

ElseIf x > 0 And x <> a And b <> lastCol Then
    'Debug.Print "Same2"
    analysisSheet.Cells(a, b).Interior.Color = analysisSheet.Cells(x, 3).Interior.Color

Else
    analysisSheet.Cells(a, b).Interior.Color = RGB(wf.RandBetween(125, 255), wf.RandBetween(125, 255), wf.RandBetween(125, 255))

End If



Next a



End Sub
```

**PS:** More efficiently while searching a key in multiple col use Find() method instead of Match().

Comment: This works for consecutive blocks, however if the column is broken then it will assign a new colour

Comment: @ohnoohdear do you mean if one of a cell in a column is Empty... if that is the case the just add a if isEmpty() condition before the first match function and ignore every empty cell to get colured

Comment: No, all cells in both columns are filled to the bottom.